# Proving that $y = a_{2n}x^{2n} + a_{2n−2}x^{2n−2} + . . . + a_2x^2 + a_0$ is an even function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, even-and-odd-functions

This question is from Larson's Precalculus book.

> Prove that a function of the form
> $$y = a_{2n}x^{2n} + a_{2n−2}x^{2n−2} + . . . + a_2x^2 + a_0$$
> is an even function.

I don't understand how that form of function is an even function?

Suppose that all coefficients are $1$ and $x=1$ and $n=2$. Then

$$y = a_4x^4 + a_2x^2 + a_0.$$

Because all coefficients are $1$ and $x=1$,

$$y = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3,$$ which is odd.

Could you please explain how am I wrong?

Comment: An even function is not one that provides even numbers! It will be even if $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Please review the definition of even function. It′s not like that.

Comment: An even function is symmetric by $f(x)=f(-x)$. It isn’t one that produces even values.

Answer (score 3):

A function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ is even if $$f(-x)=f(x), \forall x \in D.$$

So, if $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is an even number, the function $x \mapsto x^k$ is even, since $$(-x)^k=(-1)^kx^k=x^k,$$ and so the functions of the form $g(x)=cx^k$, where $c$ is a constant, is even.

Note that every exponent of the terms of the polynomial are even, so each term is even. Finally, since the sum of even functions is even, the results follows.